# Why are @font-face relative URL's loading correctly but also producing 404 errors?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, browser, fonts

There are two fonts that, although they are appearing on the site just fine, are producing errors in DevTools.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Impact;
  src: url(../fonts/impact-webfont.eot);
  src: url(../fonts/impact-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(../fonts/impact-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
    url(../fonts/impact-webfont.ttf) format('truetype'),
    url(../fonts/impact-webfont.svg#impactregular) format('svg');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: kmi-genericons;
  src: url(../fonts/kmi-genericons.eot?70543738);
  src: url(../fonts/kmi-genericons.eot?70543738#iefix)
      format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(../fonts/kmi-genericons.woff2?70543738) format('woff2'),
    url(../fonts/kmi-genericons.woff?70543738) format('woff'),
    url(../fonts/kmi-genericons.ttf?70543738) format('truetype'),
    url(../fonts/kmi-genericons.svg?70543738#kmi-genericons) format('svg');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

[image]

The paths in the console errors are incorrect. The CSS snippet above is found in `/wp-content/themes/kmi/css/compiles.min.css`. Since the path is relative, it should be loading from `/wp-content/themes/kmi/fonts/`. The network tab shows it's recognizing the correct path as well:

[image]

So it's like there are 2 requests for the same font: one at the correct relative path, and one at an incorrect root path. Why would this be?

Comment: The problem is Duplicate css style (compiled.min.css) loading in the head area.

Comment: View page source and find the issues

Comment: different issue, but don't use this loading syntax in 2018: we needed all those different formats in 2012, but lots of browsers have changed their support, and many browsers stopped being even supported. `eot` and `svg` fonts _no longer exist as formats_, and `ttf` and `otf` fonts are system level fonts, with lots of data that is not useful for webfonts, and without compression. Today, all you need is WOFF/WOFF2. Adding the other formats just wastes bandwidth, and makes it harder to debug font-face related problems. Simplify first, see if your problem's still there. If so, let's work with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, Nehemiah was correct in his comment on my question. This CSS was being inserted via JavaScript through a plugin (Above the Fold Optimization), which I didn't realize, in addition to being called from a regular `<link>` tag. Thus, it was loading twice, and the relative path did not resolve when inserted via JavaScript.

Sorry for missing this - thank you!